# How to reload Fuelux Tree with new data

Tags: ajax, tree, fuelux

Here i'm trying [Fuelux Tree](http://responsiweb.com/themes/preview/ace/1.3.3/treeview.html) used in Ace admin Template. I have used the same code they have used.

The script code used in ace admin template:

```
jQuery(function($) {

var tree_data = {};
var sampleData = initiateDemoData(tree_data); //see below

$('#tree1')
    .ace_tree({
        dataSource: sampleData['dataSource1'],
        multiSelect: true,
        cacheItems: true,
        'open-icon': 'ace-icon tree-minus',
        'close-icon': 'ace-icon tree-plus',
        'selectable': true,
        'selected-icon': 'ace-icon fa fa-check',
        'unselected-icon': 'ace-icon fa fa-times',
        loadingHTML: '<div class="tree-loading"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-refresh fa-spin blue"></i></div>'
    });



function initiateDemoData(tree_data) {

    tree_data = {
        "2C27D744B956": {
            "text": "2C27D744B956",
            "children": {
                "001B179F4400": {
                    "text": "9991100003333",
                    "type": "item"
                },
                "9991100003333": {
                    "text": "9991100003333",
                    "type": "item"
                },
                "2c27d744b956": {
                    "text": "9991100003333",
                    "type": "item"
                },
                "002170615A04": {
                    "text": "9991100003333",
                    "type": "item"
                }
            },
            "type": "folder"
        }
    };

    var dataSource1 = function(options, callback) {
        var $data = null
        if (!("text" in options) && !("type" in options)) {
            $data = tree_data; //the root tree
            callback({
                data: $data
            });
            return;
        } else if ("type" in options && options.type == "folder") {
            if ("children" in options)
                $data = options.children || {};
            else
                $data = {} //no data
        }

        if ($data != null) //this setTimeout is only for mimicking some random delay
            setTimeout(function() {
            callback({
                data: $data
            });
        }, parseInt(Math.random() * 500) + 200);

        //we have used static data here
        //but you can retrieve your data dynamically from a server using ajax call
        //checkout examples/treeview.html and examples/treeview.js for more info
    }

    return {
        'dataSource1': dataSource1
    }
}

});
```

Then on a button click i'm trying to refresh the tree, with new data from ajax Get request, But when i tried, an error comes in browser such as "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined ".

Following is my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : "getDevices.htm?did=" + dID,
            success : function(data) {

                    tree_data = data; //tree_data is the data used for the treeview

                    $('#tree1').tree('reload');
            },
            error : function(data) {
                console.log("failure" + data);
            }
    });
```

Please suggest a method to resolve this issue. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is this `$.tree('reload');` coming from? I am a maintainer of the Fuel UX library and am not aware of this method.

Comment: I got $.tree('reload');  idea from following link http://w3facility.org/question/refresh-fuelux-treeview-on-fileupload/

Comment: I don't think I'll be able to help you then, since it's not a part of the Fuel UX API. If was going to reload myself, I would use `destroy` and initialize the control again with the same datasource/AJAX call.

Comment: Is there any other way to reload or refresh the tree with new data?? Can u please at least give me an example to refer?

Comment: @InteractiveLlama : can u pls help me? how can i add new folder into tree?

Comment: Well, you can use the `cacheItems: false` option when initiating and that will always cause the dataSource to be called when a folder is opened, so that would mean you'd want to close the folder and open with a `click` event. `$().tree('destroy')` would remove everything and then you could add the tree back in the same way that you added it (initialized it) the first time. There is no single command that says add a folder. It's all based on the data from the dataSource. Here is the documentation: http://getfuelux.com/javascript.html#tree

Comment: And here are the functions that create the trees in the docs.  https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/blob/gh-pages/assets/js/tree-examples.js